# Ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, ms-access-2003

My MS-Access query is

```
strSQL = "Select pincode from pincodes  WHERE  officename = '" &area& "' AND Districtname = '" &city& "';"
```

but when I run this query it shows record not found even the value that are passing in area and city exist in ms access table

I try the code as

```
strSQL = "Select pincode from pincodes  WHERE  officename = '" &area& "';"
```

and it give correct result but I want to verify the city too but I found that two checks not perform when query for both column  how to resolve the problem I am attaching database shot from where it is retrieving value please help

[snapshot here](https://plus.google.com/photos/106958960427542160842/albums/5929296157937904609)

Comment: have you tried to query for the Districtname by itself?  If so, did it return records?

Comment: @Linger it gives record sometime and some time not show most of the time shows ADODB.Field error '80020009'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

/_____1_/pinner/actionpinn.asp, line 0

Comment: Given this and some of your other questions, it still sounds like more of a problem with data. You're getting an empty recordset - no records are being returned for what you are querying. That's not a problem with the query per se, but with the data you are searching and the data you are searching for.

Comment: Please check snap shot data is there @AnonJr

Comment: @satish Can't see the snapshot - G+ is blocked at work.

Answer (score 0):

Debug.

```
strSQL = "Select pincode from pincodes  WHERE  officename = '" &area& "' AND Districtname = '" &city& "';"
Response.write strSQL
Response.end
```

copy the output of the response.write and run it directly in the Db and see if you get any values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the data. there maybe blank spaces or something like that. Try running the query with LIKE operator:

```
strSQL = "Select pincode from pincodes  WHERE  officename = '" & area & "' AND Districtname LIKE '*" & city & "*';"
```